# Java method performs correctly when using hard-coded objects but not when using an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a basic java program which performs Dijkstra's algorithm on a set router topology. I am able to read in the topology and create ArrayLists of the routers and links between the routers. When I call the Dikstra's class with this information however it does not return the correct values, while if I manually create the routers and links it works correctly.

The hard-coded topology is identical to the one I'm reading in by file and I come up with the same set of routers and links in both cases.

Not asking for an answer as to why this is happening necessarily, maybe just something to put me on the right track. I figure it involves my use of ArrayLists but can't determine what exactly.

Thanks!

Central class lsrouter:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class lsrouter{

    //File Reading Objects
    private static lsrouter newLRouter;
    public ArrayList<router> routers;
    public ArrayList<link> links;
    private static ArrayList<String> changes;
    private static ArrayList<String> messages;


    public static void main(String[] args){

        //**This strategy returns correct distances and paths**
        router routerA = new router("1");
        router routerB = new router("2");
        router routerC = new router("3");
        router routerD = new router("4");
        router routerE = new router("5");

        ArrayList<router> protos = new ArrayList<router>();
        protos.add(routerA);
        protos.add(routerB);
        protos.add(routerC);
        protos.add(routerD);
        protos.add(routerE);

        routerA.addNeighbor(new link(8, routerA, routerB));
        routerB.addNeighbor(new link(8, routerB, routerA));

        routerB.addNeighbor(new link(3, routerB, routerC));
        routerC.addNeighbor(new link(3, routerC, routerB));

        routerD.addNeighbor(new link(1, routerD, routerA));
        routerA.addNeighbor(new link(1, routerA, routerD));

        routerD.addNeighbor(new link(1, routerD, routerE));
        routerE.addNeighbor(new link(1, routerE, routerD));

        routerB.addNeighbor(new link(4, routerB, routerE));
        routerE.addNeighbor(new link(4,routerE, routerB));

        System.out.println("adj list: "+routerA.getAdjList());
        System.out.println("adj list: "+routerB.getAdjList());
        System.out.println("adj list: "+routerC.getAdjList());
        System.out.println("adj list: "+routerD.getAdjList());
        System.out.println("adj list: "+routerE.getAdjList());
        Dijkstra shortestPath = new Dijkstra();
        shortestPath.computeShortestPaths(routerA);

        System.out.println("======================================");
        System.out.println("Calculating minimum distance");
        System.out.println("======================================");

        System.out.println("Minimum distance from A to B: "+routerB.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Minimum distance from A to C: "+routerC.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Minimum distance from A to D: "+routerD.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Minimum distance from A to E: "+routerE.getDistance());

        System.out.println("=====================   =================");
        System.out.println("Calculating Paths");
        System.out.println("======================================");

        System.out.println("Shortest Path from A to B: "+shortestPath.getShortestPathTo(routerB));
        System.out.println("Shortest Path from A to C: "+shortestPath.getShortestPathTo(routerC));
        System.out.println("Shortest Path from A to D: "+shortestPath.getShortestPathTo(routerD));
        System.out.println("Shortest Path from A to E: "+shortestPath.getShortestPathTo(routerE));

        /*
        * **Below should do the same thing(but with file input)
        * as above but does not**
        */
        String topoFileString = args[0];
        String messagesFileString = args[2];
        String changesFileString = args[1];

        try{
            newLRouter = new lsrouter();
            FileReader frTop = new FileReader(topoFileString);
            FileReader frMes = new FileReader(messagesFileString);
            FileReader frCha = new FileReader(changesFileString);
            BufferedReader brTop = new BufferedReader(frTop);
            newLRouter.readTopo(brTop);
            BufferedReader brCha = new BufferedReader(frCha);
            changes = newLRouter.readChanges(brCha);
            BufferedReader brMes = new BufferedReader(frMes);
            messages = newLRouter.readMessages(brMes);
            Dijkstra sPaths = new Dijkstra();

            for(router r : newLRouter.routers){
                for(link l : newLRouter.links){
                    if(r.getID().equals(l.getSource().getID())){

                        r.addNeighbor(new link(l.getCost(),l.getSource(),l.getDestination()));

                    }
                }
            }   

        }catch(FileNotFoundException Exc){
            Exc.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

            //This does not return correct distances and paths
            Dijkstra newDij = new Dijkstra();
            for(router r:newLRouter.routers){

                newDij.computeShortestPaths(r);
                for(router r2:newLRouter.routers){
                    System.out.println(r2.getDistance());
                }
                for(router r2:newLRouter.routers){
                    System.out.println(newDij.getShortestPathTo(r2));
                }
            }

        }


    }
    //Read in the topology file,
    public void readTopo(BufferedReader brT){

        int i;
        ArrayList<Integer> topoTemp= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try{
            while((i = brT.read()) != -1){
                char tc = (char)i;
                if(Character.isDigit(tc)){
                    int ti = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tc));
                    topoTemp.add(ti);

                }
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<router> tempRouters = new ArrayList<router>();
        ArrayList<link> tempLinks = new ArrayList<link>();
        for(int j =0 ; j< topoTemp.size(); j=j+3){
            router newRouter1 = new router(topoTemp.get(j).toString());

            router newRouter2 = new router(topoTemp.get(j+1).toString());

            link newLink = new link(topoTemp.get(j+2),newRouter1, newRouter2);
            link newLink2 = new link(topoTemp.get(j+2), newRouter2, newRouter1);

            if(!tempRouters.contains(newRouter1)){
                tempRouters.add(newRouter1);

            }
            if(!tempRouters.contains(newRouter2)){
                tempRouters.add(newRouter2);

            }
            tempLinks.add(newLink);

            tempLinks.add(newLink2);

        }
        this.routers = tempRouters;
        this.routers.sort((o1,o2) -> o1.getID().compareTo(o2.getID()));

        this.links = tempLinks;
    }
    //Read in the changes file, placing them into an arrayList of Strings
    //That we can loop through later
    public ArrayList<String> readChanges(BufferedReader brC){
        String i;
        ArrayList<String> changesTemp= new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            while((i = brC.readLine()) != null){
                changesTemp.add(i);

            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return changesTemp;
    }
    //Read in messages, placing them into an arrayList of Strings
    //That we can iterate through later
    public ArrayList<String> readMessages(BufferedReader brM){
        String i;
        ArrayList<String> changesTemp= new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            while((i = brM.readLine()) != null){
                changesTemp.add(i);

            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return changesTemp;
    }

}
```

Dijkstra's algorithm class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dijkstra{
    public void computeShortestPaths(router source){
        source.setDistance(0);
        PriorityQueue<router> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pQueue.add(source);
        source.setVisited(true);

        while(!pQueue.isEmpty()){
            router actual = pQueue.poll();

            for(link l : actual.getAdjList()){
                router r = l.getDestination();
                if(!r.isVisited()){
                    int newDist = actual.getDistance() + l.getCost();
                    if(newDist < r.getDistance()){
                        pQueue.remove(r);
                        r.setDistance(newDist);
                        //System.out.println("New distace: "+newDist);
                        r.setPred(actual);
                        pQueue.add(r);
                    }

                }
            }
            actual.setVisited(true);
        }
    }
    public List<router> getShortestPathTo(router targ){
        List<router> path = new ArrayList<>();
        for(router r=targ;r!=null;r=r.getPred()){
            path.add(r);
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

Router Class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class router implements Comparable<router>{
    private String id;
    private List<link> adjList;
    private boolean visited;
    private router predecessor;
    private int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public router(String id){
        this.id = id;
        this.adjList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void addNeighbor(link l){
        this.adjList.add(l);
    }
    public String getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String i){
        this.id =i;
    }
    public void setAdjList(List<link> aList){
        this.adjList = aList;
    }
    public List<link> getAdjList(){
        return adjList;
    }
    public boolean isVisited(){
        return visited;
    }
    public void setVisited(boolean v){
        this.visited = v;       
    }
    public router getPred(){
        return predecessor;
    }
    public void setPred(router p){
        this.predecessor = p;
    }
    public int getDistance(){
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(int distance){
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public int compareTo(router otherR){
        return Integer.compare(this.distance, otherR.getDistance());
    }
    public int hashCode(){
        final int prime =31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime*result+((id ==null) ? 0 :id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this ==obj)
            return true;
        if(this == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        router other = (router)obj;
        if(id == null){
            if(other.id != null)
                return false;
        }else if(!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Link class:

```
public class link{

    private  router source;
    private  router destination;
    private  int cost;

    public link(int cost,router source, router dest){

        this.source =source;
        this.destination = dest;
        this.cost = cost;
    }


    public router getDestination(){
        return destination;
    }
    public router getSource(){
        return source;
    }
    public int getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
    public void setCost(int c){
        this.cost = c;
    }
    public void setStart(router r){
        this.source = r;
    }
    public void setDestination(router r){
        this.destination = r;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return source + " "+ destination;
    }
}
```